# Java: Remove all instances of a certain item in an array

Tags: java, arrays

Suppose I make an array, setting the values as follows:

```
double[] exampleArray = {10.0, 3.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0};
```

How can I remove all the `0.0`'s from the array, leaving only 10.0 and 3.0 and shortening the array length to 2?

The other questions on this site involve `HashSets` or `Collections`. Is there a way without importing other stuff?

Comment: just create a new array, iterate the old array and push needed item into new array

Comment: Unless you want to make use of `System.arraycopy` extensively...importing *anything* else would make this far simpler for you.

Comment: @Makoto yes but I believe that User Yelliver's method seems to be viable

Comment: ...Considering that you can't just push elements into an array without having a predefined size...no, it's not viable.

Comment: @Makoto are arrays immutable?

Comment: Yes.  Once you create it with a defined size, the only way you can get one of a different size is to create a new one with a new size.  You're free to change the elements inside of an array at will, but once you define an array of a specific size, that ain't changin'.

Comment: @Makoto I see. So to remove all the 0's, we'd have to make a new list. What if I wanted to make it remove all the 0's from ANY list, read in from the command line?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is a one liner using streams that can get the job done:

```
exampleArray = Arrays.stream(exampleArray).filter(d -> d != 0.0).toArray();
```

Answer (score 2):

This is just an example using the int datatype.  It can be changed to suit your needs.

Explanation:
j is a counter variable that is used to size `newArray` by excluding non-zero indexes from the creation of a new array and copying all non-zero indexes to the new array.  We do this because array length is immutable in java.  Therefore, when attempting to resize an array, one must create a new array and copy.  This is the benefit of using other data structures when size mutability is required.

```
int j = 0;
for( int i=0; i<array.length; i++ ){
    if (array[i] != 0)
        array[j++] = array[i];
}
int [] newArray = new int[j];
System.arraycopy( array, 0, newArray, 0, j );
```

Comment: You should explain what this code is doing.  Also, explain why you're using an `int[]` instead of a `double[]`.

Answer (score 1):

Hope this code can help you. It is the most basic (not best) approach:

```
double[] exampleArray = {10.0, 3.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0}; 
double numberToErase = 0.0; //This could be a parameter
int newArraySize = 0;

//Get the fixed size of the new Array
for (double n : exampleArray) {
    if (n != numberToErase) {
        newArraySize++;
    }
}

//Create the new array 
double[] newArray = new double[newArraySize];
int newArrayCurrentIndex = 0;
for (double n : exampleArray) {
    if (n != numberToErase) {
        newArray[newArrayCurrentIndex++] = n;
    }
}

//Check the result
for (double n : newArray) {
    System.out.println("Number: " + n);
}
```